# quickfix MDEntryTime No Milliseconds

Tags: quickfix

I'm trying to generate an MDEntryTime with a value that contains milliseconds. The milliseconds are getting dropped once they get entered into the Message. Upon further inspection, I find this little gem inside Field.h

explicit UtcTimeOnlyField( int field, const UtcTimeOnly& data, bool showMilliseconds = false )

The constructor for MDEntryTime doesn't allow for the coder to set showMilliseconds=true. How do people get around this?

Answer (score 0):

> The constructor for MDEntryTime doesn't allow for the coder to set showMilliseconds=true.

In fact, it does. The following should work for you:

```
msg.set(FIX::MDEntryTime(FIX::UtcTimeOnly(time(NULL), true)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me. I did a method that ensure milliseconds are present in the UtcTimeOnly:

```
FIX::UtcTimeOnly getTimeMillis()
{
    timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return FIX::UtcTimeOnly(tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec / 1000);
}
```

And then, I set the field this way:

```
msg.setField(FIX::UtcTimeOnlyField(FIX::FIELD::MDEntryTime, getTimeMillis(), true));
```